# Oldest video from channel uploads or sort order for playlistItems method

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any options to retrieve a very first (older one) video from the channel? Sort order parameter will be very helpful in this case, but i can't find any (`orderby` - doesn't work).

In v2 API i can set `start-index` equal to number of uploads and just get the very first video, as well as any videos from the middle of the uploads list. Another profit - i have options to use multiple async requests or `multicurl` and get all videos from the channel at once.

Looks like in v3 of API the only way to do that - parsing `playlistItems` requests one by one using `PageToken` and `nextPageToken` parameters. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to sort the results of `playlistItems:List` without bringing down all the results from YouTube and then sorting them manually (as you suggested). The lack of a sort option does seem like a significant limitation and would be very useful to a lot of different applications!

You can track the associated enhancement request here:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6869